# How to use repeated constants and functions in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hey so I have seen a lot of posts on the user of global variables in React Native. Most posts say 'don't overdo it', while some don't have anything against it, and others encourage not doing it at all. In terms of not overdoing it, I'm not sure exactly how to quantify that. Basically the variables and functions I want to reuse are the api address (sometimes running it locally, other times running it on the cloud/if I change cloud providers want to be able to easily change it). I also want a global error handling function for when a fetch (which I have at least one in every component) gets network connection refused. I also wanted to have enums for a PUBSUB messaging system, for when a specific message body is received. If it's possible I wanted to have a global refresh token function as I am using token authentication, and if I get a token expired error, I don't want to have a repeated fetch (refresh token) function in each component. Right now I am declaring all of these in a global.js file, which I then import in my index.js file. My global.js file looks like so:

```
global.api = `http://localhost:3000`
//global.api = `https://my-todo-app.appspot.com`
global.errorString = "Something went wrong. We're prioritizing this issue. Please try again soon."
global.newTodo = 'New Todo'
global.completedTodo = 'Completed Todo'
global.cancelledTodo = 'Cancelled Todo'
const internetConnectionError = "Please check your internet connection and try again."
const alertMessage = "Something didn't go right. We're working on this issue. Please try again soon.";
global.jwtExpired = 'jwt expired'
global.handleBadConnection = function(variable) {
  Alert.alert("Connectivity Error", internetConnectionError)
}
global.handleError = function(variable) {
  Alert.alert("Wow", alertMessage)
  console.log(variable)
}
```

I have also seen to use redux and flux, but it seems to be overkill for constants. Also, I would have to intialize the entire redux reducer before when the application begins, and I'm not sure how I would do that if that is the only option.

EDIT: I also want to be able to store things into redux with a global function if this is possible

Comment: Instead of global variables, you can just have a file that has these, and export an object from that file with the information, strings, functions you need

Comment: Probably this question will be off-topic, but anyway: I do a similar thing as you do: I have a class called "Shell" (which holds some important app functions and variables), which is in a file "Shell.js", in my App.js I instantiate this class with `let shell = new Shell();`, then I do what I need to do and then I put the entire class in the global/window: `global.shell = shell;` Then I use it everywhere I need in my app

Comment: Is there any way i could connect this to redux as well, so when I fetch a refresh token (global function), I can store the results in redux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have a file that looks something like this:

Api_definitions.js:

```
export const apiDefinitions = {
    apiUrl: "192.168.1.90",
    errorHandler: (error) => {
        // do something
    },
    // any other varialbes you need here
}

(() => {
    if (environment === 'testing') {
        apiDefinitions.apiUrl = "192.168.1.15"
    }
})();
```

And in any other file I would have

```
import {apiDefinitions } from "../Api_definitions.js";
```

And then `apiDefintions` is accessible from wherever you import it. This is a normal React pattern I think.

Comment: Is there any way i could connect this to redux as well, so when I fetch a refresh token (global function), I can store the results in redux?

Comment: Well yes, but if you're using redux for that you might not have any need for this pattern in the first place

Comment: Well I didn't want to use redux for this particularly since it has a state, and I didn't want global variables that dont change to rely on a state. But I am using redux to store access tokens

Comment: Also, where did the variable environment come from in this case?

Comment: It's not supposed to be relevant to you, it's just supposed to illustrate that you can conditionally change values in the object you're exporting, and the files that import the object can see that change. It's a meaningless example.